# add another field on lookup popup

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

when creating a new contact with account name icon popup of lookup appear like below image see
[image]

I need to add one more column that "Last Modified By" after the Type column. how can i add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

follow these steps to customize the lookup popup

1. Name->Setup
2. From App Setup click on Customize
3. Select Account and expand it
4. Click on Search Layouts there you will see Look Dialogs
5. click on Edit and include the columns you want..

Let me if these steps help you out